# AWS Cognito Correct User Flow

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, jwt, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to migrate my PHP based system to AWS but the biggest thing I'm struggling with is user management/authentication side of things. I've made API Gateways and Lambda functions to get data from my RDS instance and I can use API key or ID token for authentication to protect the data they generate. What I'm really struggling with is the Cognito side of things. In my head, the system would work as follows?

1. User goes to my website and clicks the login button.
2. User is redirected to the hosted cognito UI and logs in.
3. The user is redirected to the chosen page and the id token is displayed in the URL
4. I use JavaScript to store the ID token in local storage (not sure this is the right way)
5. I can then pull the ID token out and use it in SDK to run and authenticate my APIs

In PHP I would check the session existed before loading the page to prevent users who aren't logged in accessing my system if the session didn't exist they would be redirected to the login page. How do I do this with Cognito/JWT, do I need to verify the JWT with a Lambda function at the top of every HTML page for my site? I basically want to only allow users who are signed in via Cognito user pool to have access to all the HTML, js, CSS files of my system, except the home page.

Comment: How are you hosting your static content?  If it is hosted by a server (node, php, etc) you can check the header for the token and then conditionally render your app, just like you do with the session.

If you are hosting purely static content (like in s3) then you'd have to protected routes on your app on the client side.

But in general, protecting your css and other static content will be difficult

Comment: @RobertMoskal I haven’t really thought about hosting yet. My APIs return JSON data so I was going to use javascript to parse that into tables, links etc like I used to to in PHP with the arrays returned from the databases. It’s really annoying as I know exactly how I want my system to work I just don’t have the knowledge of coding and AWS to work out the exact way I should do it. Hosting on a full stack web server wouldn’t be an issue I suppose it would allow me to use PHP which I’m very familiar with.

Comment: @RobertMoskal *" If you are hosting purely static content (like in s3) then you'd have to protected routes on your app on the client side." - I don't think it has to be client-side? If your S3 is fronted by a Cloudfront distro, you can do it via Lambda@Edge

Comment: True.  One could do that! That would be way to go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have most of the cognito stuff worked out.

If you are calling the api gateway from the web client, you are most likely passing that jwt token in the header and those api calls will fail before the user logs in.

If you are using a client side framework (React, Vue, etc), then you probably have access to a router that renders various UI components. This works analgously to what you do on the server in php, and it's pretty easy to lock down certain routes or the rendering of certain components based on a user being logged in. Doing it without a framework will probably require a significant amount of effort.

You can also stand up a php server, validate the jwt token and do what you normally do for authenticated users.

Or you could take the hyper-modern, serverless approach. You could host your html/css in an S3 bucket and put a Cloudfront distribution in front of that. You could write some Lambda@Edge functions to enforce permissions on the content in the S3 bucket.

Likely, if you are creating an api based javascript application you won't need to protect your markup/css.

Comment: That’s brilliant thanks I must admit I don’t know what a Cloudfront distribution is but I will do my research tomorrow. I’m loving building my idea and API Gateway and Lambda are so easy to learn and use but the authentication and authorisation side of things to actually secure my system is a nightmare . Than you so much for taking the time to help me out.

Comment: @MattM - you may find [this AWS Serverless App Repo example](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/authorizationedge-using-cookies-protect-your-amazon-cloudfront-content-from-being-downloaded-by-unauthenticated-users/) helpful. It illustrates the S3-Cloudfront-Cognito approach.